# In Google Analytics how do I display full URL of referring pages?

Tags: google-analytics

This is such a basic thing that I can't believe I can't find it. In the **Traffic Sources > Referrals** screen I can see a list of *domains* but where is a list of referring *pages*?

Comment: I've always wondered this myself.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom report with `Visits` as the metric from Visitors - > Visits and Referral Path as the dimension, when you view the report add a secondary dimension and select Traffic then Source which gives you the domain name. This is how I do it with the new Analytics interface, though you may be able to create this in the dashboard with the old interface without a custom report.

The Analytics API is great for pulling this data however you need and combining for complete URL's (hosts) and paths